# Kuratowski closure-complement problem for other mathematical objects?

Tags: order-theory

The original [Kuratowski closure-complement problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_closure-complement_problem) asks:

> How many distinct sets can be obtained by repeatedly applying the set operations of closure and complement to a given starting subset of a topological space?

My question is: **what is known about analogous questions in other settings?**

Here's an example of what I'm thinking of, for rings:

> How many distinct ideals can be obtained by repeatedly applying the operations of radical and annihilator to a given starting ideal $I$ of a commutative ring $R$?

Note that $r(r(I))=r(I)$ and $I\subseteq Ann(Ann(I))=\{x\in R: x\cdot Ann(I)=(0)\}$, which are the best analogs I could think of to $\overline{\overline{S}}=\overline{S}$ and $(S^C)^C=S$.

Also: **what is the structure necessary to formulate this kind of question called, and where does it occur naturally?**

It seems like we need at least a poset, but with distinguished idempotent and involution operations to generalize the closure and complement, respectively.

Comment: The radical or annihilator of an arbitrary subset of a ring is an ideal, so you'd gain exactly one set by changing "ideal" to "arbitrary subset."  

Comment: Well, unless you're working in the zero ring, every subset of which is an ideal!

Comment: Atiyah-Macdonald, p.9 says that the radical of an arbitrary subset of a ring is not necessarily an ideal - an example would be, in $\mathbb{Z}$, $rad({2})={2}$.

Comment: Ah.  I was thinking of defining the radical of a subset as the intersection of the prime ideals containing it.  This is the analogue of defining the closure of a subset as the intersection of the closed sets containing it.

Comment: Good point - that might make more sense. Well, let's just see what people come up with for the case of ideals, first.

Comment: As for your second question, I think you want something like a Heyting algebra: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_algebra .

Comment: @Qiaochu, the empty set is not an ideal of the zero ring.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a paper that might be of interest:

D. Peleg, A generalized closure and complement phenomenon, Discrete Math., v.50 (1984) pp.285-293.

Other than what's found in the above paper I do not know of any general theory or framework specifically aimed at organizing results similar to the Kuratowski closure-complement problem, i.e., those which involve starting with a seed object (or objects) and repeatedly applying operations to generate further objects of the same type in a given space.

Here's a general sub-question I thought of recently, that might be interesting to study:

"What's the minimum possible cardinality of a seed set that generates the maximum number of sets via the given operations?"

A few years ago I proposed a challenging Monthly problem (11059) that essentially asks this question for the operations of closure, complement, and union in a topological space.  It does turn out there's a space containing a singleton that generates infinitely many sets under the three operations, but it's a bit tricky to find.  I haven't looked into the question yet for other operations.  As far as I know it hasn't been discussed yet in the literature (apart from the specific case addressed by my problem proposal).

Comment: Mr. Bowron: Thanks a lot for the reference and for the Kuratowski's Closure-Complement Cornucopia!